# Compactly supported orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbf R)$ with certain properties

Tags: functional-analysis, wavelets, schauder-basis

Take a positive integer $\alpha$. I am looking for an orthonormal basis $(\phi_n)$ for $L^2(\mathbf R)$ with roughly speaking the following properties:

1. each $\phi_n$ is compactly supported and $C^\alpha$
2. consider $g \in C_0^\infty(\mathbf R)$ and the $L^2$ expansion: $$g = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \langle g, \phi_n\rangle \phi_n$$ and consider the partial sum: $$g_N = \sum_{n = 0}^N \langle g, \phi_n\rangle \phi_n$$ I want the $g_N$s to be supported within a common compact interval, ie. some neighborhood of the support of $g$.
3. nice (geometric $\mathcal O(2^{-n})$ or better) decay on $\langle g, \phi_n\rangle$ as $n \to \infty$ would be grand.

Wavelets are the first candidate but I think they do not work. Specifically, if we let $\psi$ be a $C^\alpha$ mother wavelet generating an orthonormal basis $\{\psi_{j, k} : j, k \in \mathbf Z\}$ ($\psi_{j, k}(x) = 2^{j/2} \psi(2^j x - k)$). You can get excellent (arbitrarily good increasing the smoothness of $\psi$) geometric decay on the Fourier coefficients by e.g. Theorem 5 in [https://math.unm.edu/~crisp/courses/wavelets/fall07/Sobolev.pdf](https://math.unm.edu/%7Ecrisp/courses/wavelets/fall07/Sobolev.pdf).

I believe property $(2)$ does not hold for wavelets. Take such an orthonormal basis $\{\psi_{j, k} : j, k \in \mathbf Z\}$ and expand:
$$g = \sum_{j, k} \langle g, \psi_{j, k}\rangle \psi_{j, k}$$
We can truncate using say:
$$g_n = \sum_{|j| \le n} \sum_k  \langle g, \psi_{j, k}\rangle \psi_{j, k}$$
Note that for each $j$ only finitely many $\langle g, \psi_{j, k}\rangle$ are non-zero so this is a finite sum. If we take $g$ to have support exactly $[0, 1]$, note that we may have $\langle g, \psi_{-10^5, 0}\rangle$ non-zero, at which point the support of $g_{10^5}$ may contain points near $2^{10^5}$ or something silly, though the actual values it takes near there will be tiny or be taken for a very short time. Unfortunately I want to say, for example, that truncations $g_n$ will (eventually) be supported in $[-1, 2]$ say, or so on, any compact interval will do. Is this actually possible? It must be linear combinations of the basis, I cannot multiply by a cutoff function or similar.

If I've missed any fact about wavelet theory and my concern is actually entirely invalid, please let me know as well!

Comment: I'm not sure I fully follow your argument against wavelets. For instance, why wouldn't Daubechies wavelets not work?

Comment: @StefanLafon because the truncated sum will in general have support much larger than $g$ no? Specifically isn't the union of the supports of the truncated sums unbounded? I need to be able to say that every $g_n$ is zero outside an interval $[-M, M]$ depending only on $g$. I may be mistaken in this, (I hope I am - this would rescue a proof of mine) my mental image is that given $g_n$, the support of $\psi_{-n, 0}$ will extend pretty far, not overlapping with the support of any other $\psi_{j, k}$ with non-zero coefficient.

Comment: ...hence the truncation will be $(\text{something}) + \text{something generally non-zero} \times \psi_{-n, 0}$ which will surely mean the support of the truncations will just keep growing even though the function values out there will be decreasing by cancellations from higher order terms... Have I got the right idea or am I tripping up on something?

Comment: If $V_j$ are the spaces of the father wavelet and $W_j$ the space of the mother wavelets at level $j$, so that $V_{j+1}$ is obtained from $V_j$ by shrinking its functions by a factor of $2$, then the split into trend and detail is expressed as $V_0\oplus W_0=V_1$. This can now be recursed. For good scaling and wavelet functions the limit of the $V_j$ is the full space. The combined bases of $V_0,W_0,W_1,W_2,...$ are a basis of the full space. If compactly supported, the support is bounded.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sorry, could you spell this out a bit more? Are you saying I can modify the construction of the wavelet such that this is true, ie. the truncations of the sum will indeed have support contained in that of $g$? I can't just find a basis of $L^2$ restricted to the support of $g$, this basis must work for all compactly supported $g$ and this is the behaviour that I suspect may be impossible to obtain.

Comment: Let's take the Haar wavelets as the most simple example. Then $V_0$ is the space of piecewise constant functions with jumps at the integers and $W_0$ is generated by the Haar wavelet that is constant with opposite values on $[0,1/2)$ and $(1/2,1)$ and zero everywhere else. Together they combine to the space $V_1$ of piecewise constant functions with jumps now also at the half-integers. Etc. The support of the approximations of a compactly supported functions is the smallest interval with integer end points that contains it.

Comment: @LutzLehmann This is exactly what I'm looking to do but I'm afraid I'm not understanding precisely what you're doing in the last sentence. What are you taking as an orthonormal basis here? If I took $\psi$ to be the Haar wavelet and then the orthonormal basis $\{\psi_{j, k} : j, k \in \mathbb Z\}$, this would not have the property you describe right? (sorry if these are basic questions, certainly wouldn't be offended if you referred me to a source) The negative $j$ terms are the ones of concern to me, they will be non-zero at large inputs though those values are small.

Comment: You take the basis of $\phi_{0,k}$ for $V_0$ and $\psi_{jk,}$ for $j\ge 0$ for the $W_j$.

Comment: Superb! All down to $V_0 = \bigoplus_{\ell = -\infty}^{-1} W_j$ right? Then fill in the rest with the wavelet. Amazing stuff, thank you so much. This would have never occurred to me. If you want the karma feel free to post this as an answer and I will accept it, least I can do.